# How to estimate the L2 shared memory usage on Ubuntu

Tags: performance, memory-usage, cpuinfo

I'm trying to improve the performance of one of our systems and I'm supposing that the bottleneck resides on the L2 shared memory of my CPU.

Thus, I'm looking for a way to estimate how much of my CPU shared memory it is actually being used during the perf tests.

I tried to find something useful on top manpage [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) with no success.

Comment: *Why* do you suppose that the issue is the L2 cache?

Comment: because it is not disk nor cpu itself neither secondary memory.